# Implementing a generator for keras results in worse results

Tags: python, keras

I am doing multi-label image classification on a dataset of around 3000 images. Because this is the limit of my working memory and the dataset will increase, I was trying to implement my own generator because I am also parsing the images from an online source. The network reached an accuracy of 25% where the three labels with the highest accuracy gave a pretty good representation of the images.

A normal batch would be of shape (32, 64, 64, 3) with labels of shape (32, 57).
My model looks like:

```
def createModel(shape, classes):
    x = shape[0]
    y = shape[1]
    z = shape[2]
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), padding='same',input_shape=(x,y,z)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 1), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (1, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides = 2))

    model.add(Conv2D(48, (2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides = 2))

    model.add(Conv2D(80, (2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides = 2))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(classes, activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

where classes would be 57 and the x,y,z would be 64,64,3.

My generator looks like:

```
def generator(data, urls, labels, batch_size):
    counter = 0
    X_train = []
    Y_train = []

    while 1:
        for i in range(len(data)):
            if counter == batch_size:
                yield (np.array(X_train), np.array(Y_train))
                X_train = []
                Y_train = []
                counter = 0
            try:
                ID = data[i][0]
                if random.uniform(0,1) > 0.5:
                    X_train.append(getImage(64, urls[ID]))
                else:
                    X_train.append(np.flip(getImage(64, urls[ID]),1))
                Y_train.append(labels[i])
                counter+=1
            except:
                continue
```

where data is an list with image ID and labels, urls is a list with image ID and the url to find the image, labels is the labels converted by MultiLabelBinarizer() (.fit_transform) and the batch_size. the getImage() function results in a np.array() where 64 gives the shape.

The main calls:

```
epochs = 60
lr = 1e-6

mlc = model.createModel((64,64,3), 57)

opt = Adam(lr=lr, decay=lr / epochs)

trainGenerator = data.generator(structuredData, urls, mlb_labels, 32)
validationGenerator = data.generator(structuredData, urls, mlb_labels, 32)

mlc.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics= 
["accuracy"])

mlc.fit_generator(trainGenerator, steps_per_epoch = 10, epochs=epochs, 
validation_steps = 1, validation_data=validationGenerator)

mlc.save("datagenerator_test.h5")
```

Furthermore the network thus already works and trains if I do not use the generator, with the generator it seems to get a random accuracy between 1 and 3%. I hope this provides enough information.

EDIT: I takes about 90 seconds to prepare one batch of 32 images. Does the training wait for a batch to be ready?

Comment: Are you sure you have set the `steps_per_epochs` argument correctly? i.e. you have 10 * 32 = 320 training images?

Comment: I have exactly 2455 images at the moment.So that won't be the problem I think.
EDIT: it doesn't matter if you have more right? It would just take the next batch of images the next epoch?

Comment: Your generator covers all the training samples, however in each epoch only 320 samples are generated. That means you either need to set `steps_per_epochs` correctly (i.e. `= n_samples / batch_size`) or increase the number of epochs. Then you will be able to do a correct comparison.

Comment: So each epoch should loop through all training samples?

Comment: Yes, that's what an epoch means basically.